# I'm Trying to Connect Internet with ESP32 using Cavlii C16Qs. but ESP32 is not Getting Internet Connectivity

Tags: esp32, gsm, at-command, arduino-esp32, internet-connection

I'm trying OTA Firmware update of ESP32 using Cavlii C16Qs. I'm trying to Connect internet with ESP32 using Cavlii C16Qs. Basically issue is I'm Not getting Internet Connectivity using "AT+PPPSTART" and Cavli C16Qs modem.  Cavlii C16Qs is use for Providing a LTE Network. I'm trying to Internet Connection using "AT+PPPSTART" Command. https://cavli.atlassian.net/servicedesk/customer/portal/8/topic/6c7a6bd9-155b-4438-84bb-4807e4f8db19/article/343015460 This is the link of Document for AT Commands Details. So what should I change in the below code so that esp 32 can get internet connectivity through Cavlii C16Qs? So that I can fetch the firmware file from the server.

AIM: ESP32 OTA using External modem Internet Connectivity, HTTP.h and Update.h Library.

Arduino IDE Version: 1.8.19
ESP32 Board Version: 2.0.0

Serial is use for Debug, and Serial1 is use for Serial Communication with Cavlii C16Qs.

```
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <update.h>

/* Cavli_C16QS */
String response = "";
const char *ipAddr;
String st1;
int value1, value2;
int clientID;

void setup() {
 // Power up the ESP32 by toggling the PWRKEY pin
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);

  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial1.begin(115200, SERIAL_8N1, 32, 33);  // RX, TX

  //////////////////////////////////
  // Send AT command via Serial to Cavli module
  Serial.println("Sending ATI command to Cavli module");
  Serial.println("==================================");
  Serial1.print("ATI");  // Send command via Serial2
  // FeedBack();
  delay(1000);
  while (Serial1.available()) {
    char c = Serial1.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }
  Serial.println("Sending AT+COPS?");
  //////////////////////////////////
  // Read and print responses from Cavli module via Serial2
  while (!(response.indexOf("+ATREADY") != -1 || response.indexOf("OK") != -1)) {  
    Serial1.print("AT+COPS?\r\n");                                                 
    while (Serial1.available()) {
      char c = Serial1.read();
      response += c;
    }
     Serial.print("response-->");
     Serial.println(response);
  }
  delay(1000);  // Add a delay after sending the command
  response = "";
  //////////////////////////////////
  value1 = value2 = -1;
  Serial.println("Sending AT command... +CEREG? Checking network connectivity");
  while (!(value1 == 0 && (value2 == 1 || value2 == 5))) {
    Serial1.write("AT+CEREG?\r\n");
    delay(500);
    while (Serial1.available()) {
      char c = Serial1.read();
      response += c;
    }
     Serial.print("response-->");
     Serial.println(response);
    response = "";
  }

  delay(5000);  // Add a delay after sending the command
  response = "";
  //////////////////////////////////
  value1 = value2 = -1;
  Serial.println("Sending AT command... +CGACT? Checking internet connectivity");
  while (!(value1 == 1 && value2 == 1)) {
    Serial1.write("AT+CGACT?\r\n");
    delay(500);
    while (Serial1.available()) {
      char c = Serial1.read();
      response += c;
    }
     Serial.print("response-->");
     Serial.println(response);
     response = "";
  }
  //////////////////////////////////
  delay(500);  // Add a delay after sending the command
  response = "";
  Serial.println("Sending AT+NETIF?");
  Serial1.print("AT+NETIF?\r\n");  // Send command via Serial2
  // Read and print responses from Cavli module via Serial2
    while (Serial1.available()) {
      char c = Serial1.read();
      response += c;
    }
     Serial.print("response-->");
     Serial.println(response);
     response = "";

      Serial.println("Sending AT+PPPSTART");
      Serial1.print("AT+PPPSTART=?\r\n");  // Send command via Serial2
      // Read and print responses from Cavli module via Serial2
    while (Serial1.available()) {
      char c = Serial1.read();
      response += c;
    }
     Serial.print("response-->");
     Serial.println(response);
     response = "";

  String _url = url_OTA_code_head + code_ver + url_OTA_code_tail;
  delay(2000);

  HTTPClient http;
  http.begin(_url);
  int httpCode = http.GET();
  Serial.println(httpCode);

  Serial.println("----------------------------End Setup----------------------------");
  
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Comment: You have a lot `Serial.print()` in your code, what does it shown on the Serial Monitor? My gut feeling tell me that you power up the module by toggling the pin2, and you are expecting the module immediately available a registered to the network. It doesn't work that way, move `delay(5000)` forward to where after you toggle pin2. BTW, `AT+CEREG?` does not register to the network, it check the status of registration. So is `AT+CGACT?`.. Check AT Command manual to understand more.

Comment: Thank you @hcheung for your Guidance.. I have made Correction based on your suggestions. I also attached Source code.  When I sending "AT+PPPSTART" command for PPP Connection then I'm Getting "+CME ERROR: 4" Response. 

  while (!(value1 == 1 && value2 == 1)) {
    Serial1.write("AT+CGACT?\r\n");
    delay(500);
    FeedBack();
    extractValues(response, value1, value2);
  }
  value1 = value2 = -1;
  while (!(value1 == 1 && value2 == 1)) {
    Serial1.print("AT+PPPSTART?\r\n");  // Send command via Serial2
    delay(500);
  }

Answer (score -1):

You need to use P32C1RM-Arduino library for examples

below is attached link for that library

please download it and unzip to libararies folder if you are using arduino

if you are using platfromio, just define libary in `platformio.ini` file as given below

```
lib_deps = https://github.com/cavli-wireless/P32C1RM-Arduino.git
```

[LINK](https://github.com/cavli-wireless/P32C1RM-Arduino)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35851804)